# Output is not getting string + integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,subprocess,re
f=open("/var/tmp/disks_out","w")
proc=subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
out,err=proc.communicate()
for line in out:
   f.write(line)
f.close()
f1=open("/var/tmp/disks_out","r")
disks=[]
for line in f1:
    m=re.search(r'(c.*s0)',line)
    if m:
      disk=m.group(1)
disks.append(disk)
disks = disks[0][:-1]
slices =[disks+i for i in str(range(5))]
print(slices)
```

and the out put i am getting below:

```
['c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s0', 'c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s1', 'c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s3', 'c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s4', 'c0t50                                                                                                                          00CCA025A29894d0s5', 'c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s6']
```

But i want to get output similar too:

```
c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s1,c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s2,c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s3
```

Comment: Do you want the output as a string ? if yes , `print ",".join(slices)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it with commas:

```
print(','.join(slices))
```

or rather for python 2.7:

```
print ','.join(slices)
```

What you printed out was list, so python interpreted it as one. `join()` method joins every element of the iterable by passed string, more info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (for Python 2.7 as you put in tag) but it seems you are using Python 3 here.